# Use YUI in PHP for obfuscating JS

Tags: php, yui

I'm trying to obfuscate JS file (1 or more) with my php code. It's a simple tool for the user to choose a file and do somethings with it- one of the things is to ocfuscate it. So just using YUI isn't enough- I need to implement it in my code.
To add more complex, I need to use the YUI options - Nomung etc. 
I've found nice code here: https://github.com/gpbmike/PHP-YUI-Compressor
but it has 2 problems:

1. Not all the options of YUI apear here, I need"Overwrite exsiting files" option and I don't know how to write it.
2. I'm getting this error:

> [ERROR] 1:8:missing ; before statement [ERROR] 1:0:Compilation produced 1 syntax errors. org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Compilation produced 1 syntax errors. at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.YUICompressor$1.runtimeError(YUICompressor.java:135) at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:410) at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:355) at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.parse(JavaScriptCompressor.java:312) at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.(JavaScriptCompressor.java:533) at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.YUICompressor.main(YUICompressor.java:112) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:20)

Any Ideas?

UPDATE:

I've solved the problem very easily, by simple running the java command of YUI with the exec() command: java -jar yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar myfile.js -o myfile-min.js --charset utf-8, with the needed params. Make you you place the YUI JAR file in the same folder as your php file, and that's it.

Comment: **WHY** do you need that?

Comment: 1. Have a look the code https://github.com/gpbmike/PHP-YUI-Compressor/blob/master/yuicompressor.php 2. Sounds like you have a problem in your JS

Comment: @kingcrunch- that's the code I'm using and having trouble with: How to add the option I need?